# Can The Card "Suppression Bonds" enchant a creature with Shroud

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So the description of [Suppression Bonds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Suppression%20Bonds) states:

> Enchant non land permanent. Enchanted permanent can't attack or block,
> and it's activated abilities can't be activated.

The card doesn't use the word target so basically I was confused on whether or not I could use it on a creature with shroud. Any clarification is welcome and appreciated.

P.S. If it can enchant a creature with shroud using this method, could I also use other cards that do not specifically target a creature with shroud?

Answer (score 12):

It depends on how you are enchanting the creature.

If you are casting the spell then no, you cannot enchant a creature with shroud. This is because aura spells target while they are on the stack.

> **114.1b** Aura spells are always targeted. These are the only permanent spells with targets. An Aura’s target is specified by its enchant keyword ability (see rule 702.5, “Enchant”).

If the aura is entering the battlefield due to some ability or spell just putting it there (like [Starfield of Nyx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Starfield%20of%20Nyx)'s triggered ability) you can put it on a creature with shroud, because the aura is not on the stack, therefore it doesn't target.

> **303.4f** If an Aura is entering the battlefield under a player’s control by any means other than by resolving as an Aura spell, and the effect putting it onto the battlefield doesn’t specify the object or player the Aura will enchant, that player chooses what it will enchant as the Aura enters the battlefield. The player must choose a legal object or player according to the Aura’s enchant ability and any other applicable effects.

Answer (score 3):

Suppression Bonds is an Aura and as such, it targets as per the following rule:

> **303.4a** An Aura spell requires a target, which is defined by its enchant ability.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your main question, see Diego's answer.

In response to your P.s., yes shroud only prevents the creature from being targeted - nothing else.

For example [Clone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370622), [Wrath of God](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386298), [Diabolic Edict](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397522), [Prahv, Spires of Order](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=97117), [Sovereigns of Lost Alara](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=180600), [Quest for the Holy Relic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quest%20for%20the%20Holy%20Relic) and [Bolster](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391785) do not target creatures and all work against or with a creature with shroud.

Generally things that specify 'all' of something, or things that target players can effect creatures with shroud.

There are some cards, like Clone that say 'choose' rather than target, or that do things to specific cards without using the word 'target' like Sovereigns of Lost Alara - for these, if the card is older, it is generally worth double checking, as it may have had errata like [Blue Elemental Blast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?printed=true&multiverseid=97) which on the printed card doesn't mention targeting, but has had errata to include that word*, but other than these older cards with errata you can generally choose or select a creature with shroud, so long as the card doesn't target and you aren't casting an aura or equipping an equipment.

**N.b.** Generally these cards also get around protection - Clone or Wrath of God for example ignore protection just as they ignore shroud, that said Diego's specific example (getting an enchantment on to a battlefield without casting it) doesn't get around protection like it does shroud. (Protection prevents Damage, Enchanting, Blocking and Targeting - providing the handy acronym DEBT - from anything that meets the criteria it has protection from; The classic example is that even [Progenitus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=179496) is killed by [Day of Judgement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220139))

**Example**
[Cyclonic Rift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270798) cannot effect a creature with shroud because it tries to target the creature, unless it is Overloaded, in which case it no longer targets and it instead effects 'each creature you don't control', rather than 'target creature you don't control'. You can see this verified in the first and second rulings on Gatherer for [Cyclonic Rift](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270798).

*Generally done to preserve the original intended functionality following a rule change.

Comment: Do you know of a card that said "choose" in an older printing, but says "target" in oracle? Wizards generally avoids errata that would cause functional changes without good reason.

Comment: Older as in lots older. Cards like this were generally errata'd to preserve original functionality. I believe there are cards out there printed specifically with the word choose that were errata'd to target (It's not obvious how to search printed text on Gatherer, if it is possible at all). But for the moment I'll direct you to cards like Blue Elemental Blast from Alpha - it has the word target in Oracle, but the printed version doesn't mention targeting at all.

Comment: I'll also edit my answer so that it references Blue Elemental Blast, rather than making an assertion without sources.

Comment: Interestingly the card Intuition had errata to make it choose rather than target, and then a second errata to revert it to the original text. http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/latest-developments/power-level-errata-b-gone-2006-07-14